# Why my android application showing Offers in-app purchases in playstore

Tags: android, google-play-services

I uploaded my application into Google playstore. While uploading I didnt select any options related to in-app purchases. But still it is showing **Offers in-app purchases** for my application.

Please let me know how I can disable that option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if your manifest file has this line of code asking for BILLING permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
```

Sometimes additional permissions can be added to an app by third party libraries, so check also final generated manifest file under this path: `app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml`.

If you found out that permission is added by a library you can exclude it from your project by adding this permission to main manifest file with parameter `tools:node=”remove”` like this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" 
tools:node=”remove”/>
```